# WordPress post request in my plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a post request in my plugin, but I am not sure if it is reaching the desired function or not. I try to echo, return value but nothing seems to work. Here is my jquery

```
$.post({
        url: "http://localhost/tutorials/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-post.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: "add_order"
           // parameters:parameters,
            //orderAddress : orderAddress,
            //order : order
        },
        success: function(response) {

            console.log(response);

            secondStep.hide();
            pricing.hide();
            $('.thirdStep').show();
        }
    });
```

My function on the WordPress server end is this

```
function prefix_admin_add_order() {
  echo 2; // or return 2;
}
```

Just trying to return anything from the function and trying to console log it in the response. But it doesn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: no, it comes in the success callsback.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: no error, I get no error.

Answer (score 1):

Your Php file must be as a page template and you must address it like this :
http://yourdomain.com/ajax
and in your jquery you must put this url